# chi squared and basic statistics on multiple columns of a data frame

Tags: r, statistics, plyr

I would like to compute a chi squared test for each column in a dataframe and grouping for the variable `Project`.

Basically I would like to compute a two by two table for each column and then store the value in a new table.

Here an example of my dataframe.

```
structure(list(Project = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("discovery", "validation"), class = "factor"), MLL = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), CREB = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), TNR = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Project", "MLL", "CREB", "TNR"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 300L, 301L, 302L), class = "data.frame")
```

After the comment of Jaap I have tried:

```
   pvalue <- data.frame(apply(cast_subset[-1] , 2 , function(i)   chisq.test(table(cast_subset$Project , i ))$p.value))
  colnames(pvalue) <- "p.value"
```

but i can not accces the column with the gene name for merging to other data set.

Comment: `apply` `chisq.test` over the columns of your dataframe. If df is your data `apply(df[-1] , 2 , function(i) chisq.test(table(df$Project , i ))$p.value)` . The df[-1] removes the first column from the applied function, the `2` specifies that it is applied over the columns.

Comment: Thanks! I have to get the apply function

Comment: You can access the gene names with row.names(pvalue). You can assign it to a new variable: `pvalue$gene.name <- row.names(pvalue)`. This may not be necessary as you can also merge `by` rowname.